# How to check if a radio buttons inside asp:repeater is checked or not using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have defined two radio buttons('Yes','No') in asp:repeater. Which are dynamic at run time, meaning that if the database returns 5 questions then for every question we have option ('Yes','No'). [The image attached shows the existing design of the radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJm2B.png)

Now i want to validate these radio buttons defined in asp:repeate to check if the radio buttons is checked or not using javascript/jquery. Below is the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpSuppQuestions" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpSuppQuestions_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rpSuppQuestions_ItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="div_soru_wrapper">
         <table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align: left">
            <tr>
               <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                  <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnQuestionID" Value='<%# Bind("Question_ID") %>' runat="server" />
                  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Q" CssClass="labelSmallBold"><%# Convert.ToString(Container.ItemIndex + 1) %>:</asp:Label>
                  &nbsp;
               </td>
               <td align="left">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblSuppQuestions" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Question_description") %>'
                     CssClass="labelSmallBold" Width="900px"></asp:Label>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td align="left">
                  <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="A" CssClass="labelSmallBold"><%# Convert.ToString(Container.ItemIndex + 1) %>:</asp:Label>
                  &nbsp;
               </td>
               <td align="left">
                  <table align="left">
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                           <asp:RadioButton ID="rbYes" runat="server" type="radio" CssClass="rpyes" name="tttt" GroupName="rbAnswer" Text="Yes" Font-Names="Verdane" Font-Size="10" ForeColor=" #936E85" Visible="true"/>
                           <asp:RadioButton ID="rbNo" runat="server" CssClass="rpyes" GroupName="rbAnswer" Text="No" Font-Names="Verdane" Font-Size="10" ForeColor=" #936E85" Visible="true"/>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: when you want to add this check? form submit?

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether a specific one is checked using jQuery as follows:

```
if ($("#radio1").prop("checked")) {
   // do something
}
```

// OR

```
if ($("#radio1").is(":checked")) {
   // do something
}
```

// OR

if you don't have ids set you can go by group name and value

```
if ($("input[name='radioGroup'][value='1']").prop("checked"))
```

You can get the value of the currently checked one in the group as follows:

`$("input[name='radioGroup']:checked)`;

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created the below function but is not working i.e. every time if the button is checked or not the output is “inside, if condition false”:         
function checkRadio() {
        alert("inside checkradio");
            if ($("rbYes").attr("checked", false)) 
{
                alert("inside, if condition false");
                return false;
            }
            if ($("rbYes").is(":checked", true)) 
{
                alert("inside, if condition true");
                return true;
            }   
}

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is ways to select asp.net controls using jQuery.
I recommend using `ClientIDMode="Static"`, which got introduced in .NET Framework 4.0, on the control so that it's ID will stay unchanged, your html should look like this:

```
<asp:RadioButton ClientIDMode="Static" ID="rbYes" runat="server" type="radio" CssClass="rpyes" name="tttt" GroupName="rbAnswer" Text="Yes" Font-Names="Verdane" Font-Size="10" ForeColor=" #936E85" Visible="true"/>
<asp:RadioButton ClientIDMode="Static" ID="rbNo" runat="server" CssClass="rpyes" GroupName="rbAnswer" Text="No" Font-Names="Verdane" Font-Size="10" ForeColor=" #936E85" Visible="true"/>
```

And then you can use the normal ID selector in javascript/jQuery, which whould look something like this:

```
if($("rbYes").prop("checked", true)) {
  //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created the below function but is not working i.e. every time if the button is checked or not the output is “inside, if condition false”:         
function checkRadio() {
        alert("inside checkradio");
            if ($("rbYes").attr("checked", false)) 
{
                alert("inside, if condition false");
                return false;
            }
            if ($("rbYes").is(":checked", true)) 
{
                alert("inside, if condition true");
                return true;
            }   
}

Comment: Hi again, is are your functions inside a $( document ).ready(function() {});?, if not, I will send you here [link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Give some class name to your table where radio button exist.

```
<table align="left" class='YourClass'>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <asp:RadioButton ID="rbYes" runat="server" type="radio" CssClass="rpyes" name="tttt" GroupName="rbAnswer" Text="Yes" Font-Names="Verdane" Font-Size="10" ForeColor=" #936E85" Visible="true"/>
         <asp:RadioButton ID="rbNo" runat="server" CssClass="rpyes" GroupName="rbAnswer" Text="No" Font-Names="Verdane" Font-Size="10" ForeColor=" #936E85" Visible="true"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And in jQuery check for that like below.

```
rdbArray = $.map($(".YourClass"), function(item, index){
    if($(item).find(".rpyes").prop("checked"))
    {
       return "checked"; // or whatever you want
    }
})
```